# Como utilizar un motor cc con encode en arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

La instrucciones que nos dieron para el trabajo son las suigientes: "en una simulación en tinkerCad desarrolle un código fuente y el diagrama eléctrico a partir de la siguiente figura, el programa en conjunto con el circuito debe realizar lo siguiente: "Un programa que encienda un motor CC con encoder y que este gire 20 segundos en un sentido y al cumplirse este tiempo empiece a girar en sentido opuesto, en todo momento se deberá medir la posición angular del motor e imprimirla en un display LCD, el programa debera integrar un sensor que al ser accionado cuente 2 segundos y detenga el motor, al dejar de ser accionado reinicie el funcionamiento del motor"

El codigo que estoy utilizando es este :

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

// Definir pines de entrada del encoder
#define encoderA 2
#define encoderB 3

// Definir pines del motor
#define motorPWM 9
#define motorDir 10

// Definir pin del sensor de detención
#define sensorPin 11

// Definir tiempo de giro del motor en segundos
#define tiempoGiro 20

// Definir tiempo de detención del motor en segundos
#define tiempoDetencion 2

// Definir variables
volatile int encoderPos = 5;
volatile int encoderLastPos = 6;
unsigned long tiempoInicioGiro = 10;
unsigned long tiempoInicioDetencion = 9;
bool detenerMotor = false;
bool sentidoGiro = true;

// Configurar el display LCD
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x20, 16, 2);

void setup() {
  // Configurar los pines de entrada/salida
  pinMode(encoderA, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(encoderB, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(motorPWM, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorDir, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

  // Configurar el display LCD
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();

  // Configurar la interrupción del encoder
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoderA), leerEncoder, CHANGE);
  
  // Inicializar el motor
  digitalWrite(motorDir, sentidoGiro);
  analogWrite(motorPWM, 0);
}

void loop() {
  // Leer la posición del encoder y mostrarla en el display LCD
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Posicion: ");
  lcd.print(encoderPos);
  delay(1000);

  // Girar el motor durante tiempoGiro segundos
  if (!detenerMotor) {
    if (millis() - tiempoInicioGiro < (tiempoGiro * 1000)) {
      // Calcular la velocidad del motor
      int velocidad = map(millis() - tiempoInicioGiro, 0, (tiempoGiro * 1000), 0, 255);
      
      // Configurar la dirección y velocidad del motor
      digitalWrite(motorDir, sentidoGiro);
      analogWrite(motorPWM, velocidad);
    } else {
      // Detener el motor y cambiar el sentido de giro
      detenerMotor = true;
      tiempoInicioDetencion = millis();
      analogWrite(motorPWM, 0);
      sentidoGiro = !sentidoGiro;
    }
  } else {
    // Detener el motor durante tiempoDetencion segundos
    if (digitalRead(sensorPin) == LOW) {
      detenerMotor = false;
      tiempoInicioGiro = millis();
    } else if (millis() - tiempoInicioDetencion >= (tiempoDetencion * 1000)) {
      detenerMotor = false;
      tiempoInicioGiro = millis();
    }
  }
}

void leerEncoder() {
  int MSB = digitalRead(encoderA);
  int LSB = digitalRead(encoderB);

  int encoded = (MSB << 1) | LSB;
  int sum = (encoderLastPos << 2) | encoded;

  if (sum == 0b1101 || sum == 0b0100 || sum == 0b0010 || sum == 0b1011) {
    encoderPos++;
  }

  if (sum == 0b1110 || sum == 0b0111 || sum== 0b0001 || sum == 0b1000) {
encoderPos--;
}

encoderLastPos = encoded;
}
```

Con este codigo solamente logramos que en el diplay lcd se imprima el valor de 5 pero el motor no gira. puden ayudarme porfavor.